# How to retrieve json data from database to laravel blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel to build my system and I needed to send multiple option from drop down input field and it was done successfully by sending as `json_encode`.

but when I retrieve data to laravel blade, it display like this:
`["Sinhala","Englis"]`

How can I show it without brackets and commas? I tried `json_decode` and an error occurred [image: (see image)]

my database is like this [image: Database]

My Controller function

```
public function index(){
    $courses = Course::get();
    return view('Courses.courses')->with('courses', $courses);
}
```

Comment: You need to loop it. Using `@foreach` of laravel

Comment: what should be the variable then ?

Comment: It gives error as `Array to string conversion` when `json_decode` , 'json_encode` gives result as `"[\"Sinhala\",\"Englis\"]"`

Comment: @user3263347 you can check my answer for making string of array after json decode function.
Also show output

Comment: [Spatie's MediaLibrary package](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v8/advanced-usage/using-custom-properties/) allows you to get info from JSON format automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this using the json_decode function so you got the array of the values then make string using the implode function with comma separated.

```
<?php

$data = '["Sinhala", "English"]';

$data = json_decode($data);

echo implode(', ', $data);
```

Output

[image]